# vbscript to change protectet view mode to edit or normal mode

Tags: vbscript

I have automated VB script and it will be do the following tasks:

1. It will allow user choose the excel sheet
2. Inserts the macros into chosen excel sheet
3. Export (SaveAs) into `.xls` format (which has macros)

But the problem is step (1), all Excel sheets are in "protected View". Every time I have to change the protected view to edit mode manually then move further. Is there any way that I can change this setting through VB script only to avoid manual intervention?

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a reference to each worksheet in turn, and use the `Unprotect` method, providing the password if necessary.

Comment: I have tried this below code its not working. Could you please help me out on my problem
Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0 Then
Set wbPV = ActiveProtectedViewWindow.Edit

Comment: None of what you have there is correct.  edit your question and post the code you have written already in there.  You can use a `For Each` loop to iterate over all worksheets.  If the worksheet is protected, then `Unprotect` it as I mentioned previously

Comment: @Dave. How to do the using **vb script**.I know in previous line of code is in vba and its working fine.

Comment: You can use a `for each` loop and the `unprotect` method of a worksheet in `vbscript` just fine.  I reiterate, please post your code and I (and probably others) will help you to fix it.